# list.push_back seems to duplicate the last added element

Tags: c++, list

> Input: This_is_a_[Beiju]_text
>
> Expected output: This_is_a_[Beiju]_text
>
> Actual output: This_is_a_[Beiju]_textt

It seems when the code ends, it adds an extra unwanted char (note the extra "t" at the end).
Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

using namespace std;
int main() {
    list <char> text;
    char current_char;
    while(true){
        // Revisa si llegamos al final del archivo
        if(cin.peek() != char_traits<char>::eof()){
            cin >> current_char;
            text.push_back(current_char);
        }
        else{
            break;
        }
    }
    for (auto itr = text.begin(); itr != text.end(); itr++){
        cout << *(itr);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because of the newline character.

Your input is actually `This_is_a_[Beiju]_text\n`. When `cin` peeks the `\n` it doesn't see an EOF yet. When `operator>>` then tries to read the next character, it fails, because it ignores the line break as whitespace and then hits the EOF. And so the value of `current_char` stays the same as the previous read. Which means you'll insert a duplicate of the last character into your list.

You can use this instead:

```cpp
while(cin >> current_char){
  text.push_back(current_char);
}
```

`cin` evaluates to `false` when it reaches EOF, i.e. it will stop the loop if it can't read anything anymore.